# How do I check if certain keys exist in JsValueLookups in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm brand new to Scala (and I have never used Java). I'm working on a project where there's this code

```
  def doAccountUpdate(account: db.models.Account, config: JsObject, job: JsValue) : JsValue = {
    val params = job \ "params"
    Account.update(account, config, params)
    Json.obj("account" -> account.toJson())
  }
```

Params here are params from a client like a browser, mobile app, etc. That code calls another function (that `Account.update`) that updates our DB and ships off the update to a 3rd party partner. The JSON looks like:

```
...
identity" : {
    "name" : {
        "givenName" : "Rdlbnl0",
        "familyName" : "Smith",
        "legalName" : "Rdlbnl0 Smith"
    },
contact" : {
    "address" : {
        "street" : "1234 N Main St",
        "city" : "Portland",
        "state" : "OR"
    },
...
```

I've been tasked with *only* sending the blocks of JSON that have an updated value inside from the client. So, as an example, if `givenName`, `familyName`, or `legalName` is updated I would send along the whole "identity" block, but not the contact.

If I was writing JavaScript (my strongest lang) the code would look something probably like

```
var params = [
    "givenName"
];

var hasUpdatedName = params.some(function(v) {
    return ["givenName", "familyName", "legalName"].indexOf(v) != -1;
});

// => hasUpdatedName == true
```

Once I know which ones exist I can verify that value is different, but figuring out which keys exist like my JS example I'm struggling to figure out.

Comment: I would use Argonaut for this - it has combinators to search for elements in a JSON structure and if it is there returns a Some type and if not then None.

Comment: When you say 'only send' do you mean 'only return' or 'only pass to the `Account.update` method'? If the latter, it will mean modifying that method, right? If the former, you might be able to get away with just using a `filter` on the object you're returning.

Comment: @NathanielFord It would probably go in the file not listed here that actually constructs the JSON blob with Json.obj. That file already has some conditional stuff like if it's an update to an existing account it adds an account number. That type of thing.

Comment: oh, and to clarify, I mean _return_. So the file that makes the JSON blob would return a JSON blob that doesn't have the "contact" block.

Comment: @OscarGodson The question is a little confusing then: you show a function that calls `update` on `Account`, and returns a JSON-type object. Are you looking to modify the return value of `doAccountUpdate`, or modify the behavior of `Account.update`, or something else?

Comment: @NathanielFord I can modify the JSON fine, I'm just looking for how to get a boolean if a key exists in params. Once I know if that's truthy I can do what I need. But I'm not sure how to do like `if (params.contains([a, b, c]))` (in pseudo code)